# How to sum from 100 file - bash/awk?

Tags: bash, awk, paste

I need to sum up values from 100 files. This is part of my input
suma_wiazan_wodorowych_2_1.txt

```
2536
1928
1830
1774
1732
1673
1620
```

suma_wiazan_wodorowych_2_101.txt   (name for every file is changing by 100, so 1, 101, 201 etc)

```
2535
1987
1895
1829
1805
1714
1657
```

So my script should add first row from the first file first row from the second file .... to one hundred
2535+2536+..+..+2621
And against the second row from the first + second row from the second file etc.
The length of every file is 5000 rows (so I will have 5000 sums)
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one-liner using `paste`and `bc`

```
paste -d + suma_wiazan_wodorowych_2_* | bc
```

assuming the lines contain only bare numbers without a leading `+` (negative numbers, that are, numbers with a single leading `-`, are ok), and the files have equal number of lines.

Answer (score 3):

with `awk`

```
$ awk '{sum[FNR]+=$1} END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print sum[i]}' file*
```

sum all corresponding values from all input files, print at the end.